# MongoDB building query with OR condition from an array

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I want to create and run a query using MongoDB C++ api having these conditions :

1. *timestamp* is within a range AND
2. From an array of strings, atleast one of them to be equal to the *type*

I have these fields in my MongoDB document:
**id_, timestamp, type**

I have used builder stream to create my query. For the first condition to filter timestamp I did :

```
Document doc_timestamp;
doc_timestamp << "timestamp" << open_document <<
    "$gt" << startTS <<
    "$lte" << endTS
  << close_document
```

If I run the first condition alone, it runs perfectly. But I am not sure how to do it for *type* field. I did like this:

```
Document doc_type;
auto arr_type = doc_type <<
"$or" << open_array;
for (auto nNum : nTypes) {
    arr_type = arr_type << "type" << std::to_string(nNum);
}
arr_type << close_array;
```

This filter does not work. It throws a run time error. What is wrong I am doing here? Also, how do I concatenate these two filter and pass it the *find* function to run the query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the `$or` is the best option for the array filter. If you want to find if an element is present in an array you can use the `$in` [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in)

There have been [some discussions about building a bson array in a loop](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/ggkTtUxuGUE/JDkmEXONDAAJ) like how you tried, but even @acm suggested there to use the `bsoncxx::builder::basic` instead of `bsoncxx::builder::stream`.
With `bsoncxx::builder::basic::array{}` you can append all the types to the array and use it directly in the query with the `$in` operator.

Regarding how to concatenate both filters, they can just be added one after the other:

```
using namespace bsoncxx::builder::stream;

// Some random start/end time and types
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point from_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - std::chrono::hours(5);
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point to_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::hours(5);
const auto types = { "xls", "docx", "pdf" };

auto array_builder = bsoncxx::builder::basic::array{};
for (const auto& type : types ) { array_builder.append(type); }

mongocxx::cursor cursor = db["query"].find(
    document{} <<
        "timestamp" << open_document <<
                            "$gt" << bsoncxx::types::b_date{ from_time } <<
                            "$lt" << bsoncxx::types::b_date{ to_time } <<
                       close_document <<
        "type"      << open_document  <<
                            "$in" << array_builder <<
                       close_document <<
    finalize
);

for (auto doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
```